# make a change to an element within a list within a list

Tags: python, list, csv

i am reading a csv file into a data:

```
def get_file(start_file): #opens original file, reads it to array
  with open(start_file,'rb') as f:
    data=list(csv.reader(f))
```

i need to go through every row and add a value to row[1] like this. initially `row[1] = 'Peanut'`, i need to add 'Butter' so the result would be

```
row[1]='PeanutButter'
```

i need to do this for every row like this

```
for row in data:
  row+='Butter'
```

is this the correct way of doing it?

Comment: -1 You just asked this exact question. Go and clarify that instead of starting a new one.

Comment: its a different question entirely

Comment: It's exactly the same question, with a very *very* minor modification. The problem is how to modify every line of an iterable, you're just changing the modification that you want.

Comment: no man, last question i asked about to add a column, in this question i am asking how to add a string to the same column for every record

Comment: Well, yes. That's like asking how to add two to a number, and then a bit later asking how to subtract one. I've *copy-and-pasted* the code from the last answer into here.

Comment: No worries. You should try to understand the way this is done, because it will make this (and future issues with handling the data) much easier. Please do ask if you'd like me to explain the code a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want

```
for row in data:
    row[ 1 ] += "Butter"
```

but the right way to do this is not to iterate through every row of `data` *again* but to modify the way you generate `data` in the first place. Go look at my answer in your other question.

---

#### Copy-paste from your previous question

```
def get_file( start_file )
    f = csv.reader( start_file )
        def data( csvfile ):
            for line in csvfile:
                line[ 1 ] += "butter"
                yield line
    return data( f )
```

which you use like

```
lines = get_file( "my_file.csv" )
for line in lines:
    # do stuff
```

#### Explanation

The issue here is that we want to modify the data held in `data`. We could look through and change every element in `data`, but that's slow, especially given that we're going to look through every element again shortly. Instead, a much nicer way is to change the lines as they are *inserted* into the data holder, because that saves you one pass.

Here goes:

`f = csv.reader( start_file )`

I have modified the code to use `csv.reader`, because that's a much more robust way of reading CSV data. It's basically a trivial change; it works like `open` but each line is a tuple of the values, already separated for you.

`def data( csvfile )`

This is different! Instead of making data a variable, we're making it a function. That doesn't sound right, but bear with me.

`for line in csvfile:`

OK, `data` is a function of `csvfile` so we're just iterating through the lines in the first argument. So far, so good.

`line[ 1 ] += butter`

This is the change you wanted to make: we add "butter" to the second element of `line`. You could also make other changes here: add a column to each row, delete columns, skip rows, the list goes on!

`yield line`

This is clever Python trickery. It basically works like `return`, but *without stopping the function from running*. Instead, it is paused until we ask for the next value.

So now `data` is a function which returns each of the lines (modified just as you wanted them) in turn. What now? Easy:

`return data( f )`

Make `get_file` return `data`!

What does this mean? Well, we can now use it as the iterable in a for loop:

`for line in get_file( "my_file.csv" ):`

and everything will work!!! Magic!! =p

A couple of other points:

- Previously, you used `with ... as ...` syntax. This is a `context manager`: it automatically closes the file when you're done with it. But in this case we don't want to do that, since we are reading lines from the file *as we go through*. Casting it to a `list` copies the whole thing into memory, which is sloooooow. You should add f.close() elsewhere in the code if you're worried about memory leaks.
- I had another point, but I can't remember it...

Comment: wowowow!!! thank you so much!! i learned a HUGE amount from this post. i really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
for flist in data:
    for element in flist:
         element += 'butter'
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: no i believe that this writes to every element in flist, i need to write only in the a specific column